# alias_attribute method in rails model not working when using the "record[:col]" syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, alias, symbols

I'm doing some backend work (xls-scraping) for an accounting/finance rails app, and I'm wanting to allow a table to accept multiple accounting entity tags for the same column

So I'm using the `alias_attribute` method in my models to accomplish this

```
class DouglasAudit
  #...
  alias_attribute :new_alias_name, :actual_column_name
  alias_attribute :net_rental_income, :net_rental_revenue
  #...
end
```

Aliasing like this is very useful to me because I can scan these **dreadfully** diverse spreadsheets, searching for metatag matches which are then converted *directly* into symbols to be called on the respective model to store their respective data like so (pseudo-codey, the actual code is much more dense):

```
spreadsheet[0] = [Roo::Excel(filename), property_id]
rows_to_scrape.each do |rownum|
  rowtag = spreadsheet[0][0].cell(rownum, "A")
  if @tags_wanted.include?(rowtag)
    d = DouglasAudit.find_by_ssid(spreadsheet[0][1])
    tagvar = variableize(rowtag).to_sym # 'variableize' converts "Hello World" into "hello_world", etc
    d[tagvar] = spreadsheet[0][0].cell(rownum, "E")
    d.save
  end
end
```

If I had an alias for the `net_rental_revenue` mentioned above (the 2nd named variable), when :net_rental_income is passed into the DouglasAudit instance (`d[:net_rental_income]`) nothing happens. Due to the nature of the ar_object[:col] method no error is thrown but the data is not saved.

I really like being able to use the ar_object[:col] method for dynamic programming. What is going on here to trip this up and what are some good ways around it?

-- I am trying to avoid using eval() but answers using eval are still technically valid albeit less secure

Comment: There's a comment on the apidock.com's alias_attribute documentation page (http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) that says alias_attributed is deprecated?